# nodejs embed database with search features

Tags: node.js, database

Im looking for advice in what are good options to use Database embed directly in NodeJS using a module or similar, because Im using electron to make a Desktop application (Win/Lin/Mac) and I want to create the less quantity of threads and extra process.

Really I need a simple DB, I going to work with JSON objects, with keys, and values, but I need a fast, disk storage (non-memory DB, need to be saved in disk to update/remove/add), with the posibility to make search in some fields, for example:

```
[
  "2g1hg3h2g3": {
    "title": "nanananananana",
    "description": "the nanana thing",
    "layer": "D5D5D5"
 },
  "gf1h23fh1g2f3": {
    "title": "pipipi",
    "description": "the pipipi thing",
    "layer": "F3F3F3"
 }
```

]

And the db allow me to search like obj[x].title LIKE '%pi%'
I know is possible to use MySQL, MongoDB and similar with node, but require to create another process started with the application as external server, and im looking for some "embed" system.

Comment: SQLite is commonly used as an embedded database: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3

Comment: appear what im looking for, thanks!